# Deleting strings from text file

Tags: linux, string, file, awk, sed

I have a txt file, like this:

```
| abc_0123        | CREATE_COMPLETE      | 2020-02-17T12:03:27  | D4F5                        |
| defgh_0456       | CREATE_COMPLETE      | 2020-02-28T13:25:15  | G6H7I8
…
```

I only want to keep:

```
abc D4F5
defgh G6H7I8
```

I tried:

```
sed -i 's/| abc_0123        | CREATE_COMPLETE      |/abc/g' text.txt
```

It works, but can't get rid of the date.

Comment: Start with the easy part: `awk '{print $2, $5}' FS=\|`

Comment: So the first line of your input ends in `|` but the second line doesn't, and your input file has DOS line endings (`\r\n`), right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat input
| abc_0123        | CREATE_COMPLETE      | 2020-02-17T12:03:27  | D4F5          
| defgh_0456       | CREATE_COMPLETE      | 2020-02-28T13:25:15  | G6H7I8
$ awk '{split($2,a, "_"); print a[1], $5}' FS=\| input
 abc  D4F5                        
 defgh  G6H7I8
```

Although you might prefer to get rid of more whitespace with:

```
awk '{split($2,a, "_"); print a[1], $5}' FS='[| ]*' input
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK

```
awk -F"|" '{print $2, $NF}'
```

explanation :

```
awk -F"|"  -- Set field separator as pipe (|)
'{print $2, -- Print second column
$NF -- Print last column. NF is an internal variable that stores number of fields.
}'
```

Demo :

```
:>echo "| abc_0123        | CREATE_COMPLETE      | 2020-02-17T12:03:27  | D4F5  "  | awk -F"|" '{print $2, $NF}' 
 abc_0123          D4F5  
:>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]|_]+' '{print $2, $7}' file
abc D4F5
defgh G6H7I8
```

or if the parts in the middle don't always look like you showed then:

```
$ awk -F'[[:space:]|_]+' '{print $2, $(NF-1)}' file
abc D4F5
defgh G6H7I8
```